# Facebook Graph API / FQL : Is it possible to know which one of two users has unfriended the other one?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-fql

Using Facebook FGraph API or FQL, can I know if userA has unfriended userB if I have all userA permissions?

In fact, here's what I'd like to achieve:

There are two users for whom I have *all* permissions. They are friends together (I can see it using the API).

One day, I see that they are not friends together anymore and I'd like to know **which one of the two has unfriended the other one**. Is it possible, in a way or another?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm pretty sure the best you can do is detect that they're no longer friends because they're not listed in each other's friends list.

However, Facebook makes a point of banning any application that lets people know when someone unfriends them.